# What is the difference between a sitemap an architectural blueprint and a task flow?

Tags: information-architecture, sitemap

As I understand and so far I have been reading about this, sitemaps would only show pages and relations between them. An architectural blueprint would show pages, pages components and relationships between them and well...task flows would show the flows among a certain task.

Are these three definitions correct?

And do you have maybe an example of an architectural blueprint?  I do not quite understand the difference and the importance on having a sitemap and a blueprint. Are both necessary for the deliverables to the client?

Comment: It is common in UX design to get too caught up in the terminology. Of course, people need a common set of terms to communicate ideas, but in the end it is about what assets they want you to  deliver, regardless of what it is actually called. Architectural blueprint is too abstract as it can apply to any aspects of the UX design/architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been thinking about this for an hour; have to admit "architectural blueprint" had me stumped.  Do you actually mean a wireframe? I *think* you are looking for the following document definitions:

**Sitemap** - Site architecture in a hierarchy, with clear categorization of pages. It's where the pages "live" in the organization, but not necessarily the order users will see them.

- [Random google image example.](http://www.ceri-mines.org/images/sitemap.jpg)

**Userflow/Flow** - Shows the path or paths a user can take to complete a task. Pages show up in viewing order for the user, not with a categorical hierarchy. Decision logic is usually also included in this chart (either user decisions or system decisions).

- [Random google image search](http://elizabethrsmyth.files.wordpress.com/2011/05/useraccounts_userflow-01.jpg)

**Wireframe** (architectural blueprint) - The core components of an individual page, communicating hierarchy, UI patterns, logic, content types, and potentially structure. Its a representation of how the interface might work, although it's not the final visual design or layout.

- [Random google image example.](http://cdn.teamddm.com/includes/files/assets/images/large/1328757969_wireframe-stiles.jpg)

Hope that helps! Good luck.